# What set does $\mathbb W$ denote?

Tags: notation, definition

> What set does $\mathbb W$ denote?

I know this may horribly lack context, but I've seen multiple times on M.SE $\mathbb W$ used in some fairly elementary context I think.

Comment: Can you link some examples ? $W(s)$ usually denotes Lambert's Omega Function btw.

Comment: @RenatoFaraone I don't have any examples at hand, sorry. That's why I added "I know this may horribly lack context", hoping you can cope with that.

Comment: Somebody asked a professor at my university what a whole number was, and his response was "A number like zero, six, eight, nine... They all have holes in them."

Comment: Sometimes $\{W_t : t\ge 0\}$ is the "Wiener process", named after Norbert Wiener, modeling Brownian motion.  For each $t\ge 0$, $W_t$ is a normally distributed random variable with expected value $0$ and variance $t$, and increments are independent, i.e. for every finite $n$ with $0\le t_1\le s_1\le t_2\le s_2\le\cdots\le t_n\le s_n$, the random variables $W_{s_k}-W_{t_k}$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$ are independent. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @RenatoFaraone The question says it is a set, so it can't be a function.

Comment: @user89167 ops my fault, but usually sets are denoted with bbb style.

Answer (score 6):

In an elementary context, $\Bbb W$ means the set of whole numbers. Some books have it as

$$\Bbb W=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$$

while others have it as

$$\Bbb W=\{1,2,\ldots\}$$

Because of the ambiguity, I recommend that you avoid the use of $\Bbb W$. For the second meaning use $\Bbb Z^+$. There still is no perfect abbreviation for the first. Either meaning is also called the [Natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number), although usually the Whole numbers are meant to be different from the Natural numbers. Again, we see the ambiguity: even if the Whole and Natural numbers are different, which is which? See the Wikipedia articles for a variety of notations for these sets, most of which are far from perfect.

I have occasionally seen the phrase "whole numbers" used for the [Integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer), which includes negative numbers such as $-1,-2,\ldots$ and is usually written $\Bbb Z$. But I have never seen the notation $\Bbb W$ used in that way.

As @RenatoFaraone points out, in an advanced context $W(x)$ probably means the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). But I have never seen that written in the "blackboard bold" style that $\Bbb W$ uses.

Comment: You're right, bbb-style is used for Set Theory while the $W(x)$ notation is proper of the Lambert's function.

Comment: In what are whole numbers assumed to be different from natural numbers? From both your definition and the Wikipedia article (not to mention the MathWorld page) they seem to be pretty much the same thing...

Comment: @A.P.: I have seen them treated differently in multiple books. MagicMan's answer cites one. Another that I have taught from is *Algebra 2* by Holliday, published by Glencoe McGraw Hill. Both books (if I recall correctly) have zero in the Whole numbers but not in the Natural numbers--not at all what I prefer. As I wrote, there is much ambiguity in the matter.

Answer (score 3):

Just to provide a more or less authoritative reference as to what $\mathbb{W}$ denotes, the following is from page 2 of the book [*A Transition to Abstract Mathematics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123744806) by Randall Maddox:

[image]

As you can see, $\mathbb{W}$ denotes the set of whole numbers, but this notation is often avoided in favor of $\mathbb{N}$, and even $\mathbb{N}$ itself is often clarified at the beginning of a text or mentioned in context whether or not $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$.

Also, I should mention that this book *never* makes use of $\mathbb{W}$ after page 2. It seems to be almost universally avoided and for good reason.

Comment: This is just a convention in Maddox's book. Usually, whenever ambiguity may arise authors state at the beginning weather they assume $0 \in \Bbb{N}$ or not.

Comment: @A.P. Fair point. By "authoritative," I really meant something along the lines of "this notation actually appears in the mathematical literature and here is a description" as opposed to "this is *the* definition...". Maybe that makes more sense. And yes, what you mentioned at the end of your comment concerning $\mathbb{N}$ is what I meant in the penultimate paragraph of my answer--the definition of $\mathbb{N}$ being used is nearly always clarified at the outset. At least that's been my experience when reading books and papers.

Answer (score 1):

The [natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number), $\mathbb N$, are sometimes called the whole numbers, $\mathbb W$. It's ambiguous, because $-1$ is also a *whole* number, since it has no fractional parts.